# Why does io.Pipe() continue to block even when EOF is reached?

Tags: go, io

While playing with subprocesses and reading stdout through pipes I noticed interesting behaviour.

If I use an `io.Pipe()` to read the stdout of a subprocess created through `os/exec`, reading from that pipe hangs forever even when EOF is reached (the process is finished):

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/echo", "Hello, world!")
r, w := io.Pipe()
cmd.Stdout = w
cmd.Start()

io.Copy(os.Stdout, r) // Prints "Hello, World!" but never returns
```

However, if I use the built-in method `StdoutPipe()` it works:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/echo", "Hello, world!")
p := cmd.StdoutPipe()
cmd.Start()

io.Copy(os.Stdout, p) // Prints "Hello, World!" and returns
```

Digging into the source code of `/usr/lib/go/src/os/exec/exec.go`, I can see that the StdoutPipe() method actually uses `os.Pipe()`, not `io.Pipe()`:

```
pr, pw, err := os.Pipe()
cmd.Stdout = pw
cmd.closeAfterStart = append(c.closeAfterStart, pw)
cmd.closeAfterWait = append(c.closeAfterWait, pr)
return pr, nil
```

This gives me two clues:

1. File descriptors are being closed at certain points. Critically, the "write" end of the pipe is being closed after process start.
2. Instead of `io.Pipe()` as I used above, `os.Pipe()` (a lower level call that roughly maps to `pipe(2)` in POSIX) is used.

However I am still unable to understand why my original example behaves the way it does after taking into account this newfound knowledge.

If I try to close the write end of an `io.Pipe()` (instead of an `os.Pipe()`) then it appears to break it completely and nothing gets read (as if I'm reading from a closed pipe even though I thought I passed it to the subprocess):

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/echo", "Hello, world!")
r, w := io.Pipe()
cmd.Stdout = w
cmd.Start()

w.Close()
io.Copy(os.Stdout, r) // Prints nothing, no read buffer available
```

Okay, so I guess an `io.Pipe()` is quite different than an `os.Pipe()`, and probably doesn't behave like Unix pipes where one `close()` doesn't close it for everybody.

Just so you don't think I'm asking for a quick fix, I already know I can achieve my expected behaviour by using this code:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/echo", "Hello, world!")
r, w, _ := os.Pipe() // using os.Pipe() instead of io.Pipe()
cmd.Stdout = w
cmd.Start()

w.Close()
io.Copy(os.Stdout, r) // Prints "Hello, World!" and returns on EOF. Works. :-)
```

What I'm asking for is *why does io.Pipe() seem to ignore an EOF from the writer*, leaving the reader blocking forever? A valid answer could be that `io.Pipe()` is the wrong tool for the job because `$REASONS` but I can't figure out what those `$REASONS` are because according to the documentation what I'm trying to do seems perfectly reasonable.

Here is a complete example to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "os/exec"
  "io"
)

func main() {
  cmd := exec.Command("/bin/echo", "Hello, world!")
  r, w := io.Pipe()
  cmd.Stdout = w 
  cmd.Start()

  io.Copy(os.Stdout, r) // Blocks here even though EOF is reached

  fmt.Println("Finished io.Copy()")
  cmd.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Your process still has the write side of the pipe open.  So io.Copy is blocking waiting until you close it.  This is expected behavior.

Comment: EOF hasn’t been reached. EOF is when you close the pipe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"why does io.Pipe() seem to ignore an EOF from the writer, leaving the reader blocking forever?"  Because there is no such thing as "EOF from the writer".  All an EOF is (in unix) is an indication to the reader that  no processes hold the write side of the pipe open.  When a process attempts to read from a pipe which has no writers, the `read` system call returns a value that is conveniently named EOF.  Since your parent still has one copy of the write side of the pipe open, `read` blocks.  Stop thinking of EOF as a thing. It is merely an abstraction, and the writer never "sends" it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a goroutine:

```
package main

import (
  "os"
  "os/exec"
  "io"
)

func main() {
   r, w := io.Pipe()
   c := exec.Command("go", "version")
   c.Stdout = w 
   c.Start()
   go func() {
      io.Copy(os.Stdout, r)
      r.Close()
   }()
   c.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pipe writer is never be closed compared to the one created by `StdoutPipe()`.

You need to close it manually:

```golang
  cmd := exec.Command("/bin/echo", "Hello, world!")
  r, w := io.Pipe()
  cmd.Stdout = w 
  cmd.Start()
  go func() {
    cmd.Wait()
    w.Close() // or w.CloseWithError() if exec error
  }
  io.Copy(os.Stdout, r)

  fmt.Println("Finished io.Copy()")
  // No need to wait again
  // cmd.Wait()
```